# MutationObserver callback doesn't fire for EMBED nodes

Tags: javascript, opera, mutation-observers

For some reason, the following code snippet just logs "false" 1000+ times, but never "true". I can't figure out why, because it seems to work for any other element.

```
// create an observer instance
// log whether the mutation is made to an EMBED node
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.dir(mutation.target.nodeName == 'EMBED');
  });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  attributes: true, // required
  childList: true, // required
  characterData: true, // required
  subtree: true // get updates from the descendants, not just the children
};

// start observing immediately
// this works because "document" always exists
observer.observe(document, config);
```

I'm testing the code on this page, in the latest Opera:

https://www.facebook.com/ccstandup/videos/vb.331786510170444/1177307595618327/

(If you use the latest Opera, it should be a Flash video implemented with EMBED, but in other browsers it could be VIDEO.)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `embed` element itself actually change, or are you expecting it to fire when the flash video changes? MutationObserver emits changes when the DOM changes, but the rendered content in an `<embed>` is not in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is the element that has had a change happen to it. When an element is inserted, it isn't that element that changes, but its parent. Checking `mutation.target.nodeName == 'EMBED'` will check if `attributes`, `childList` or `characterData` of the embed element had changed, which they haven't. If you need to see when the `embed` element itself is inserted, you need to look at it from the point of the of a parent element, e.g.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type !== 'childList') return;

    mutations.addedNodes.forEach(function(node){
      if (node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return;

      var embed = node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'embed' ? node :
          node.querySelector('embed');

      // Found an embed element.
      if (embed) console.log(embed);
    });
    console.dir(mutation.target.nodeName == 'EMBED');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes so much sense now :)